# How to extract specific string on a web page using Python

Tags: python

Here's the complete HTML Code of the page that I'm trying to scrape so please take a look first https://codepen.io/bendaggers/pen/LYpZMNv

As you can see, this is the page source of mbasic.facebook.com.

What I'm trying to do is scrape all the anchor tags that have a pattern like this:

**Example**

```
<a class="cf" href="/profile.php?id=100044454444312&amp;fref=fr_tab">
```

**Example with wild card.**

```
<a class="cf" href="*">
```

so I decided to add a wild card identifier after href="*" since the value are dynamic.

**Here's my (not working) Python Code.**

```
driver.get('https://mbasic.facebook.com/cheska.cabral.796/friends')
pagex = re.compile(driver.page_source)
pattern = "<a class=\"cf\" href=\"*\">"
print(pagex.findall(pattern))
```

Note that in the page, there are several patterns like this so I need to capture all and print it.

```
<td class="w n" style="vertical-align: middle"><img src="https://scontent.fceb2-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/cp0/e15/q65/p50x50/79342209_112439723581175_5245034566049071104_o.jpg?_nc_cat=108&amp;_nc_sid=dbb9e7&amp;efg=eyJpIjoiYiJ9&amp;_nc_ohc=lADKURnNsk4AX8WTS1F&amp;_nc_ht=scontent.fceb2-1.fna&amp;_nc_tp=3&amp;oh=96f40cb2f95acbcfe9f6e4dc6cb31161&amp;oe=5EC27AEB" class="bo s" alt="Natividad Cruz, profile picture" /></td>
<td class="w t" style="vertical-align: middle"><a class="cf" href="/profile.php?id=100044454444312&amp;fref=fr_tab">Natividad Cruz</a>
<td class="w n" style="vertical-align: middle"><img src="https://scontent.fceb2-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/cp0/e15/q65/p50x50/10306248_10201945477974508_4213924286888352892_n.jpg?_nc_cat=109&amp;_nc_sid=dbb9e7&amp;efg=eyJpIjoiYiJ9&amp;_nc_ohc=Z2daQ-qGgpsAX8BmLKr&amp;_nc_ht=scontent.fceb2-1.fna&amp;_nc_tp=3&amp;oh=22f2b487166a7cd06e4ff650af4f7a7b&amp;oe=5EC34325" class="bo s" alt="John Vinas, profile picture" /></td>
<td class="w t" style="vertical-align: middle"><a class="cf" href="/john.vinas?fref=fr_tab">John Vinas</a>
```

My goal is to print or **findall** the anchor tags and display it in terminal. Appreciate your help on this. Thank you!

Tried another set of code but no luck :)

```
driver.get('https://mbasic.facebook.com/cheska.cabral.796/friends')
pagex = driver.page_source
pattern = "<td class=\".*\" style=\"vertical-align: middle\"><a class=\".*\">"
x = re.findall(pattern, pagex)
print(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your wildcard match needs a dot in front like `.*`

I'd also recommend using a library like Beautiful Soup for this, it might make your life easier.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a parsing library, such as `BeautifulSoup` or `requests-html`. If you want to do it manually, then build on the second attempt you posted. The first won't get you what you want because you are compiling the entire page as a regular expression.

```
import re

s = """<a class="cf" href="/profile.php?id=100044454444312&amp;fref=fr_tab">\n\n<h1>\n<a class="cf" href="/profile.php?id=20004666644312&amp;fref=fr_tab">"""

patt = r'<a.*?class[="]{2}cf.*?href.*?profile.*?>'
matches = re.findall(patt, s)
```

Output

```
>>>matches
['<a class="cf" href="/profile.php?id=100044454444312&amp;fref=fr_tab">',
 '<a class="cf" href="/profile.php?id=20004666644312&amp;fref=fr_tab">']
```

Comment: Hi Eric! Thank you for helping out. The thing is, the "/profile.php?id=100044454444312&amp;fref=fr_tab" href value are dynamic. Its not always like this.

Comment: You can just remove ```profile.*?``` but, in that case, there is no need for href at all  in the regex because every <a> element will have an href attribute. It is trial and error to find exactly the correct regex.

Comment: thanks for your advice Eric I'm using selenium right now as I can easily simulate mouse clicks in facebook page. Not sure about requests-html as I have no idea on this library. Though I have a beginner knowledge in BS. I'll look into that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by the previous respondent, BeautifulSoup is the best thats available out there in python to scrape web pages. To import beautiful soup and other libraries use the following commands

- from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
- from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

Post this the below set of commands should solve your purpose

```
req=Request(url,headers = {'User-Agent': 'Chrome/64.0.3282.140'})
result=urlopen(req).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(result, "html.parser")
atags=soup('a')
```

**url** in the above command is the link you want to scrape and headers argument takes by browser specs/version